# Unable to autowire dependencies into WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an existing Spring web service with a `web.xml` file and a combination of xml-config and java-config. (Primarily xml config because my coworkers still think it's 2009.)

I'm trying to add a dynamic filter registration based on properties. Namely, if a particular boolean property is set, it needs to add one kind of filter, and if it's not set, it'll add a different filter.

I'm trying to do this by implementing `WebApplicationInitializer`.

The implementation looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=Foo.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:svc.properties")
public class WebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Value("${dev.mode:false}")
  private boolean isDevMode;

  @Autowired
  Foo foo;

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    // use the web.xml as the base
    XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/web.xml");

    if(isDevMode) {
      FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("jwtFilter", devModeFilter());
      filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,true,"/blah/*");
    } else {
      FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("jwtFilter", jwtFilter());
      filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/blah/*");
    }
  }

  @Bean
  public DevModeFilter devModeFilter() {
    DevModeFilter filter = new DevModeFilter(foo);
    // config here
    return filter;
  }

  @Bean
  public DevModeFilter jwtFilter() {
    JwtFilter filter = new JwtFilter(foo);
    // config here
    return filter;
  }
}
```

The filter registration is working -- I can put breakpoints into it and it works great.

The problem is that `foo` is always null, and the `@Value` annotated property always takes the default value. (Foo is a bean, annotated with `@Component` with an autowired constructor that as a parameter an instance of another bean that's declared in an `@Bean` elsewhere in the app.) I can put breakpoints both in the filters themselves and in the `onStartup` method and they trigger as expected, right up to the point where they need to interact with `foo` (which is always null).

The web.xml is normal and otherwise functions. It does declare the contextConfigLocation of the spring xml config files in it, which have the appropriate `<context:component-scan />`, `<context:annotation-config />`, `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, configs etc.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="FooApp" version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/service-base.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- listeners, servlets, and filters config'd here -->
</web-app>
```

How can I get my properties file and autowired dependency here so I can register a (spring bean) filter dynamically? I realize that this is probably due to my use of `WebApplicationInitializer`, which is managed by the servlet and not by Spring, but I'm having difficulties finding Spring-based alternatives.

I'm not allowed to use Spring-Boot or profiles. (Policy, not my own personal decision.)

Comment: You cannot auto wire in a `WebApplicationInitializer` it sole purpose is to bootstrap the context, so it doesn't even exists. Just use profiles, register a `DelegatingFilterProxy` in your `web.xml` and based on the profile load one or the other filter in your context. no need to make it more complex.

Comment: Nope, not allowed to use profiles either.

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use profiles? Those are nothing more then setting properties, just are you are doing now. You could even use your own property to enable/disable profiles using an `ApplicationContextInitializer`. Also you are overthinking things, just add an `@Configuration` class create a single `@Bean` method which returns the appropriate filter based on your property. Use a `DelegatingFilterProxy` in your `web.xml` (which you probably already have).

Comment: I don't write policy, I just have to do the appropriate contortions to work around its restrictions. :) You should add an answer with your @Config/@Bean suggestion.